# Comments have a pointless "edit" button, even after the 5 min timeout has expired

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically remove the edit link for comments once they are no longer editable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62403/automatically-remove-the-edit-link-for-comments-once-they-are-no-longer-editable)

My own comments have an "edit" button. When I edit my comment after the 5 min edit timeout expired, it is still possible to click it and edit the comment. However, when wanting to save it, you get a message stating that it's too late to save the comment. I find this annoying.

Comment: I guess with all the other real-time stuff active on the question pages, it might not be too bad to remove the "edit" button based on the 5 minute timer expiring.

Comment: -1 because you're unable to propose a new feature in a remotely constructive manner. Even when someone helpfully moderated the tone of your request, you continued your pointless tirade in [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133924/comments-have-a-pointless-edit-button-even-after-the-5-min-timeout-has-expire#comment372107_133928) rather than learning from it.

Comment: I find it annoying that someone is using my gravatar and making half-baked suggestions on meta to besmirch my public image.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is by design.  If you remove the edit link after 5 minutes, then there will be *nothing* there to tell people that they can no longer edit.  This would almost certainly lead to an endless succession of "what happened to the edit link?" questions being posted here on Meta.

Note: If it really were a *button* you could disable it and display it in a non-active state.

Comment: Then make the "edit" link non-clickable or if it must be clickable, show a popup "Sorry, time's up". It is extremely frustrating to start editing just to find that you can't save and all your edits were a **WASTE OF TIME**, an **EXERCISE IN FUTILITY**. Sysiphos was a more happy man than those of us running into that trap. How sucky can a user interface get?

Comment: @Jens Your incredibly negative attitude about the site's user interface is detracting greatly from your feature request.  Please try to be more constructive.

Comment: It's not about the site's user interface, it's about this one problem. I have repeatedly lost time in the edit box. And it's frustrating. Apparently many think this is a feature needing no attention, let alone a fix. That only adds to frustration.

Comment: @Jens I understand being frustrated, but all the hyperbole and statements like "How sucky can a user interface get" are rather abrasive (to me, at least).  As you can see, one of the Stack Exchange developers already removed the initial rant from your post.

Comment: @Jens start writing faster and you'll be an happier man