# Could we fade / tuck away / ... the "edit comment" link so it does not appear available after it's too long to edit?

Tags: feature-request, comments, usability, user-experience

I posted [Why is ReactJS not performant like raw JS for simple, stupid proof of concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126566/why-is-reactjs-not-performant-like-raw-js-for-simple-stupid-proof-of-concept/32131187#32131187), walked away, came back, and realized I'd stated a setInterval() delay as 100 seconds when I meant 100 milliseconds. It still had its edit button, which allowed me to attempt an edit, try to save, and be told it was more than five minutes since I'd posted.

Could we improve the "edit" button so it gives or emotes some sense of decay or a window closing? That would be better than instantly hiding the "edit" button when five minutes have passed, which would in turn be better than leaving the "edit" button (potentially) indefinitely and looking like a live invitation to edit the comment in question.

I'm not sure what kind of decay could be best (could be a sine wave in opacity or something else that has been beaten to death), but I would suggest that the "edit" button look (in some sense) solid up until some threshold before five minutes, then decays (however approached) between the threshold and five minutes, and then quietly slips away when the 5 minute threshold is crossed.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62403/automatically-remove-the-edit-link-for-comments-once-they-are-no-longer-editable

Comment: Definitely related. But I think something that communicates a closing window (fading is one option) is a tad better even if the related question deals with the most important aspect.

Comment: And one other thing that might be avoided: Now, you click "edit" and it lets you edit a whole response and submit it before being told 5 minutes has past. That's a little rude.

Comment: Well lets see what happens to this feature-request as the old one if from year 2010.